# IIS 7.5 on Windows 7; I Can reach "Default Web Site", from my MAC, but none of the other hosted sites

Tags: windows-7, vpn, mac-osx, iis-7.5

I'm using VPN and Microsoft Remote Desktop to access my work Windows 7 VM. I need to get my Windows 7 machine to serve SAMClientDev (see screenshot), so that I can access it from my MAC, but I keep getting "web page is unavailable" errors. **Any help would be MUCH appreciated.**

**More Info**

**SAMClientDev IIS bindings:** Host Name: dev-us.localhost.mycompany.com, Port: 80, IP Address: *

**Url I am using in my browser:** my-machine-name.dev-us.localhost.mycompany.com

**Note:** I *can* reach "Default Web Site" fine (I get the default iis page).

UPDATE:

Another caveat is, that dev-us.localhost.mycompany.com is used by everyone in the company for local dev, so will I need to change the bindings to a different host name e.g. dev-us.my-machine-name.mycompany.com?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website bindings are `dev-us.localhost.mycompany.com` so why are you pointing your browser to `my-machine-name.dev-us.localhost.mycompany.com`? That's going to take you to the default website. You need to point your browser to `dev-us.localhost.mycompany.com` and you need a name resolution mechanism (DNS) to resolve that name to the ip address of the web server.

Comment: Right.. The dev-us.localhost.mycompany.com is the address that the IIS server is looking to resolve.  Make sure that you have that DNS name on the DNS server that can resolve this effectively.  If you are running that server on a client PC that gets dynamic IP addresses, its better to setup a CNAME record for dev-us.localhost.mycompany.com to point to yourcomputername.yourcompany.local

Comment: @joeqwerty - this is not my area of expertise :) My Windows 7 machine is serving the site, but it's not Windows Server if that makes a difference. Another caveat is, that dev-us.localhost.mycompany.com is used by everyone in the company for local dev, so will I need to change the bindings to a different host, say, dev-us.my-machine-name.mycompany.com? I have no control over the DNS' but I believe they will accomodate me. So I just need to tell them to point dev-us.my-machine-name.mycompany.com to my IP address of my machine then, correct?

Comment: If you need to access the website from other hosts then yes, you'll need to change the bindings to `dev-us.my-machine-name.mycompany.com` (or anything other than localhost) and have your administrators add a matching DNS record.